# How to enable 8.0 preview in Visual Studio build 16.1

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I updated to Visual Studio build 16.1 and can not figure out how to enable C# 8.0 previews features. Previously, if I used an 8.0 feature the lightbulb would allow me to enable the previews.

Now a message tells me if I want to use the preview features I will need to enable them.  The only setting I can find  has a checkbox for enabling "Use previews of the .NET core SDK", but it doesn't enable them.

Any applications that I had previously enabled the previews still compile, so the preview software is on my machine.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I used an 8.0 feature the lightbulb would allow me to enable the previews.

You can only use the lightbulb within Visual Studio on Preview Visual Studio builds.  Release builds like 16.1 doesn't have that particular feature.  Enabling C# 8.0 language support is a feature of 16.1 and was previously tested within Preview builds (hence the lightbulb).

> The C# compiler determines a default language version based on your project's target framework or frameworks. When your project targets a preview framework that has a corresponding preview language version, the language version used is the preview language version. When your project doesn't target a preview framework, the language version used is the latest minor version.
> For example, during the preview period for .NET Core 3.0, any project that targets netcoreapp3.0 or netstandard2.1 (both in preview) will use the C# 8.0 language (also in preview). Projects targeting any released version will use C# 7.3 (the latest released version). This behavior means that any project targeting .NET Framework will use the latest (C# 7.3).

Source: [Select the C# language version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

> Now a message tells me if I want to use the preview features I will need to enable them. The only setting I can find has a checkbox for enabling "Use previews of the .NET core SDK", but it doesn't enable them.

You can set the language version in your .csproj file add the following XML element.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can also do it from within Visual Studio 2019 16.1.

> You can set the version in Visual Studio. Right-click on the project
> node in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Select the Build tab
> and select the Advanced button. In the dropdown, select the version.
> The following image shows the "latest" setting:
>
> [image]

Source:

- [Select the C# language version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)
- [Add support for Nullable build setting](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4058)
- [How to enable Nullable Reference Types feature of C# 8.0 for the whole project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633538/how-to-enable-nullable-reference-types-feature-of-c-sharp-8-0-for-the-whole-proj)

You should also verify you have the preview feature enabled that allows you to use previews of the .NET Core SDK

[image]

Comment: The option to select C# 8.0 will appear if you are targetting the correct version of the .NET Framework (specifically the correct version of .NET Core).  I don't have any version of the .NET Core installed so I cannot provide a screenshot with the correct selection.

Comment: <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion> or  <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion> in csproj file worked - Thank you!