# No option to enable preview released of .NET Core

Tags: .net-framework, sdk, visual-studio-2019

I just installed Visual Studio 16.1.0 recently.  I can no longer target .NET Standard 3.0 or .NET Core 3.0 and when I go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > .NET Core there is no checkbox to enable preview releases.

[image]

I do have .NET Core 3.0.100-preview 4 installed as well

[image]

I have repaired Visual Studio, uninstall/install, and for some reason, I have no option to enable preview releases.  I'm hoping that this will also solve my TFS build issue since my machine is a build agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have repaired Visual Studio, uninstall/install, and for some reason, I have no option to enable preview releases. I'm hoping that this will also solve my TFS build issue since my machine is a build agent.

You are looking in the incorrect location.

[image]

Source: [Use Previews of the .Net Core SDK CheckBox is now missing from VS 2019 in Tools --> Options](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/576973/use-previews-of-the-net-core-sdk-checkbox-is-now-m.html)

> I do have .NET Core 3.0.100-preview 4 installed as well

Having the .NET Core SDK installed isn't actually required to enable this particular feature.

Comment: Related: [How to enable 8.0 preview in Visual Studio build 16.1](https://superuser.com/questions/1439616/how-to-enable-8-0-preview-in-visual-studio-build-16-1)